# Budget probleme because of css file import

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I'm a junior developer, I haven't got a lot of experience and I work currently on a big Angular project.
We use Angular Material and create custom themes for our application.
We have a global style.scss file in which we import all others globals files (for button global style for example), 2 theme files in which we put the respective colour palette and some predefined variables, and at least a variables.scss file in which we define our theme.

Before I arrived on this project, my co-worker used global variable to custom element like this `var(--primary)`. But now, we want to change this and don't use global variable anymore.
So now, I use the mat-color function. It allows me to call my predefined property in the theme file :

```
// Predefined property in theme file
// Background palette for light theme.
$background-color: (
  background: #FAFAFA,
  border:     #D8D8D8,
  white-bg:   #FFFFFF,
  hover:      rgba(white, 0.04),
  card:       #FFFFFF,
  dialog:     map_get($mat-grey, 800),
  disabled-button: #B9C2CB,
  stroked-button: map-get($mat-blue, 50),
  focused-button: $light-focused,
  selected-button: map_get($mat-grey, 900),
);
```

When I need to change the colour of a specific component and this can't be done in the global scss file, I do like that :

- I import the variables.scss file in the component.scss
- I use mat-color to call predefined property.

Example :

```
@import 'variables';

.article {
border: solid 1px mat-color($background-color, border);
}
```

So far, everything works ! My problem here is we have a budget, and because of this variable file import in some component.scss, the budget just explosed.

I look after a solution to continue to call my predefined variable without explode the budget.
I'm not experienced enough to really understand the budget and why my imports made it grows.
If someone can explain me and has a solution for me, I'll be very glad to read it !

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Try not to import the variables i the component.scss. The IDE might should show some warning but I think it still work. If you by budget means size?

Comment: I try to not import the variables, but the compilation failed if I do it. I can't use mat-color without importing variable, I guess.
Yes it's something like that, and this size grows a lot when I import variables :/
I try also to import only the theme file but it doesn't work.

Comment: How big is the variables.scss file?

Comment: 1.4Ko, we use jenkins to check our PR on github and it says the budget was exceeded by 630Ko. I import variables in 8 component.scss. Does the variables.scss import all the material angular library each time I import it in a component ?

Comment: I have not managed to successfully work with sass in components. I have found it difficult when I cant override a components style when ex its located beneath some other class in the page. And I have had my thoughts about theming. What I have done is to structure the sass files inside the styles folder. Then you don't need to import ex the variables over and over again. Have a look at this: https://www.sitepoint.com/8-tips-help-get-best-sass/. The first section Structure Your Sass. If you can live with the drawbacks. The corr. components scss will be located in the styles/components folder

Comment: There is some workaround you can do with @mixins but Im not sure how far one can take it. https://coryrylan.com/blog/sass-and-css-import-performance-in-angular. Until something else comes up Ill keep the specific component style located in styles, the most important part is to be able to locate the component style in a single file. So I don't use styles/style in the Angular components.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the documentation, it was really interesting (I begin also with Sass :) ). We are ok with the structure, only little details don't follow the first article, but I don't think it is the cause of my problem.
I think the problem comes maybe with your second link. I have to check how it operates, because I think I'll have a lot of duplicate code. Thanks for you help, I will do some tests.